# Push notification for Iphone App using Flex mobile developement

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, flex-mobile, flex4.6

Iam working with a flex mobile project which requires push notifications for both android and ios .Already done the android part using flex native extensions adding ane file. Interested to know about the IOS procedure

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here - http://flashsimulations.com/2011/12/16/apple-push-notification-service-native-extension-for-adobe-air/

Comment: According to the comments, that ANE doesn't work any more. There's a working alternative, though. Check http://forums.adobe.com/thread/940310

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it worked in my project

Follow the steps provided in adobe devnet site 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-push-notifications.html

You have to create an account in urban airship to implement this

Answer (score -1):

You need to use AIR 3.4 as Push Notifications is part of that release for both iOS & Android.

Comment: Android push notifications are not natively supported with AIR 3.4, so you'd still need an ANE for that. On iOS it works nicely, though.